# Can we have a poly time reduction from 2-SAT to 2-Coloring problem?

Tags: reductions, satisfiability

I know that given a 2-Coloring instance we can easily convert it into a 2-Sat instance in polynomial time . Is the reverse possible? i.e given a 2-sat instance can we convert it into an 2-Coloring instance in poly time?

Comment: Yes. 2-SAT has polynomial time algorithms. You can simply solve the 2-SAT instance and if the instance has a solution you create a graph  that is 2-colorable, like for instance a graph with only two connected vertices. If the instance of 2-SAT has no solution, you create a graph that is not 2-colorable like for instance the complete graph with three vertices. But i think this is not what you want to do. Am i right?

Comment: You are probably looking for a weaker reduction, such as a logspace reduction or an AC0 reduction.

Comment: yes @rotia . that is not what I wanted to do . I wanted to infer that 2-sat is in P since 2-color is in P.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As rotia mentions in their comment, to make the question meaningful we must restrict the power of the allowable reductions. The two most obvious choices are to allow only logspace reductions or only AC<sup>0</sup> reductions.

Since 2SAT is NL-complete (with respect to logspace reductions) whereas 2COL (2-colorability) is in L (this is a non-trivial result which follows from Reingold's theorem), if there is a logspace reduction from 2SAT to 2COL then L=NL, which is considered unlikely. Hence we do not expect such a reduction to exist; a fortiori we do not expect an AC<sup>0</sup> reduction to exist.

Comment: Thank you for explaining . I am not conversant with log space reductions at the moment . Surely gonna look them up